# Docker inode exhaustion when pulling image from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, storage, dockerhub, inode

I'm trying to pull an image from Docker Hub (this one: https://hub.docker.com/r/openmicroscopy/omero-server/). When I run `docker pull openmicroscopy/omero-server` I get the following output:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from openmicroscopy/omero-server
5e35d10a3eba: Already exists 
4c7f892860a0: Pull complete 
8eef538af010: Pull complete 
7ce54f93fa6f: Pull complete 
67e4ee84001a: Extracting    581MB/581MB
873bd90af4ef: Download complete 
2c29661b3a9e: Download complete 
eb230c33fb76: Download complete 
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar: no space left on device
```

I have enough space left. However, when I watch `df -i` I do see that my /var inode usage briefly goes to 100%, after which the process ends with the error message shown above.

Docker info:

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: nvidia runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 62.71GiB
Name: cn1147.irc.ugent.be
ID: F52F:JVNR:XL6V:7UED:AGIS:H3VW:GN54:YBYR:SY3Q:QGPK:K45X:NVYU
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker version: `Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`

As you can see in the info output I'm using overlay2, which should not suffer from any inode issues. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems your file system does not have enough inodes, or put in another way, there are already too many files stored on it.

Comment: Indeed, the /var partition was too small. I moved my docker directory to another partition, which solved the problem! Follow the guide [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169).